# Is EE able to handle this db/site ok?

Tags: database, 404, cache

It's quite a "general" question.

- Our site has 60k posts.
- Each post has 10-15 relations and almost 50 custom fields and several categories options. Mostly focused in one channel.
- One category group has more than 1000 sub-categories inside.
- Grows 150 users a day.
- Users became "posts" as we use Zoo Visitor.
- We use Ce Cache to cache posts.

Just need to know if we are ok to grow this way. We are having several 404 (error 500) after a server migration, and things are becoming slower week after week. Running on a dedicated server @hostgator. Receiving only 4k unique visitor each day.

**Should EE be able to handle this db volume without problems? 
I read something about php as cgi not a good practice?**

[image]

Comment: I think you might more responses if you limit to one question per post.  It would take pages and answer all this.

Comment: All in all, i think EE can handle this easily. I've seen several big sites tha do this and more. However, i think you'll need to be clever in caching, and maybe spread the load over multiple servers an/or work with load balancers. Maybe also stuff like varnish could help you.
Php as cgi has not worked in my advantage in the past. Also, maybe hostgator isn't the best if you're getting serious in your hosting. Try nexcess or digitalocean